# How do I initialize output numpy arrays in numba function?

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I have a function that calculates a value open angle

```
@njit(cache=True, nopython=True)
def coord_unit_vec(latlon_vec):

    lat_vec = latlon_vec [:, :, 0]/(latlon_vec [:, :, 0]+latlon_vec [:, :, 1])
    lon_vec = latlon_vec [:, :, 1]/(latlon_vec [:, :, 0]+latlon_vec [:, :, 1])

    return lat_vec, lon_vec

@njit(cache=True, nopython=True)
def calc_oa(latlon, oa_skip):
    X_LAT, X_LON = coord_unit_vec(( latlon[:,2 * oa_skip : ] - latlon[:,oa_skip : -oa_skip]))
    Y_LAT, Y_LON = coord_unit_vec(( latlon[:,: -2 * oa_skip] - latlon[:,oa_skip : -oa_skip]))
    OA = np.empty(dtype=np.float64)
    OA = nan2zero(np.arctan2(Y_LAT, Y_LON) - np.arctan2( X_LAT, X_LON ))
    OA [OA>= np.pi] -= 2*np.pi
    OA [OA<= -1*np.pi] += 2*np.pi
    return np.degrees(OA)
```

But it keeps raising a typing error, with not much more info to go off of

```
TypingError                               
...
    <source elided>
    OA = np.empty(dtype=np.float64)
    OA = nan2zero(np.arctan2(Y_LAT, Y_LON) - np.arctan2( X_LAT, X_LON ))
```

Please help me understand how to do typing better?

Comment: Please provide a *full reproducible* example. Not parts of it. This is especially important for Numba.

Comment: Could you please also provide your version of numba. Note that the error messages have improved a lot in more recent versions.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You do not need to, just let numba initialize the output array for you.

The problem I see is your line `OA = np.empty(dtype=np.float64)`. Here you want to allocate an array, but you are not providing the shape. You could use the convenience function `OA = np.empty_like(Y_LAT)` which will allocate an empty array of size and data type as `Y_LAT`. However, looking at your next line (which is an assignment and throws away the previously allocated array), you do not need to manually allocate the array, because numba will do the work for you. The argument of your (not provided) function `nan2zero` which is `np.arctan2(Y_LAT, Y_LON) - np.arctan2( X_LAT, X_LON )` will already allocate an array and fill the array with the output of the given calculation.
Note, that in your helper function `coord_unit_vec` you also do not need to manually allocate and initialize `lat_vec` and `lon_vec`. This is done by numba for you.

So remove the line `OA = np.empty(dtype=np.float64)` and maybe for better readability split the next line to get

```
[...]
# the mathematical expression which defines the value and does the allocation
OA = np.arctan2(Y_LAT, Y_LON) - np.arctan2( X_LAT, X_LON )
# some polishing for the numerics, e.g. removing NaNs.
[...]
```

Comment: I've tried both options previous to this, I added the np.empty, as an attempt to fix the same issue being caused even with code as you mentioned.  
```
OA = np.arctan2(Y_LAT, Y_LON) - np.arctan2( X_LAT, X_LON )
``` 
still gives me the same error